# Least Squares solution for a musical note

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, least-squares

I'm trying to build a simple least-squares denoiser using linear algebra. Given a note in form A*sin(2πft) and a set of noisy sine data I'm trying to figure out a way to create a Ax = b form so I may do a linear algebra approximate least-squares solution on the noisy data.

I've been trying for a while, and begin to worry this is not possible. Is this at all possible while remaining within Linear Algebraic methods?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932900/least-squares-fitting-using-cosine-function

Comment: I'm not sure how I see that is applicable, or lack the experience to strongly relate the formula y=b+ccos(x) to A*sin(2πft), as the first is an addition of a single variable to a cosine function, while this one is the multiplication of a variable with a sine function containing multiple variables. I cant find an identity for sin(AB) to break it apart, for example.

Comment: Since versus cosine is not relevant.  If it can be solved with a constant offset, $b$, it can be solved under the assumption $b = 0$.

Comment: @RNPF Do we know the frequency $f$ in advance? If so, then Eric's link is indeed along the lines of what you're looking for. If not, then I don't think that this can be solved as a linear algebra problem.

Comment: Sadly, f is what ideally would be solved for, so not known.

Comment: @RNPF The most obvious approach to me in this case is to use gradient descent. I don't believe that this is solvable with purely linear algebraic methods. In the case of polynomial best fits, the outputs obtained by the candidate function are a linear function of the coefficients of interest, but that is not the case here.